# Add extra fields to my UserCreationForm from my extended User model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I need two extra fields for the user data so I followed the official django docs [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user), the admin form for users works fine but I have a UserCreationForm and I want to add the two extra fields in that form too, already tried to use two forms, the UserCreationForm and the form for my extended user model but I can't get the id of the UserCreationForm to fill the user_id of my extended user model so I search how to use a signal to do that like the django docs recommend and find this [Django Signals: create a Profile instance when a new user is created](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/model-creation-onetoone-relationship-signals-django-admin#django-signals) but that only fill the user_id of my extended user model that is the OneToOneField but not the two extra fields.
sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you tried using `ModelForm` for your extended model? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: I tried this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918355/how-to-extend-usercreationform-with-fields-from-userprofile but don't save the extra fields

Comment: No, but how can I use the ModelForm for my extended model to save the extra data in the UserCreationForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to run but here's a quick implementation. It needs some tweaks apparently but should get you started:

```
# this is your model form for extended OneOnOne with user
class ExtendedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = ExtendedModel
    # temporary exclude user field to pass the validation
    exclude = ('user')

def create_user(request):
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    extra_form = ExtendedForm(request.POST or None)

    if user_form.is_valid() and extra_form.is_valid():
        # create a new user first
        new_user = user_form.save()
        # create an object in memory but not save it
        new_extended_obj = extra_form.save(commit=False)
        # assign the user to the extended obj
        new_extended_obj.user = new_user
        # write to database
        new_extended_obj.save()
```