# What is the correct way to auto-create related model objects in django-registration?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm a total Django newbie and apologize in advance if I'm not using the correct terminology.

I'm using django-registration to register user on my web-app. I've successfully adapted it work with my custom user model `GeneralUser`.

Conceptually, each `GeneralUser` has a `Business`, another model that I've defined. Whether this is the correct decision or not, I've decided that I never want to register a user without a related `Business` object.

I've read countless threads on customizing django form, and finally after a few days of unsuccessful attempts, came upon [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11918448) that helped reach a solution. However, I am unsure that my code is correct/safe. This is **my** adaptation, followed by the linked-answer:

**my adaptation**:

```
class GeneralUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    business_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GeneralUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1',
                  'password2', 'business_name']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=True)
        business = Business(name=user.business_name, owner=user)

        # notice: no if-block
        user.save()
        business.save()
        # notice: returning only a user-instance
        return user
```

This code successfully creates a user and a business object, and creates the relationship. Looking at the original answer code though, I wonder if there isn't something critical I'm missing:

**Answer I based my code on:**

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    job_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    age = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
        user = super(UserCreateForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, job_title=self.cleaned_data['job_title'], 
            age=self.cleaned_data['age'])
        user_profile.save()
        # notice: multiple returns
        return user, user_profile
```

A few questions about the differences:

- Why doesn't **my code** work if I end it like this:

.

```
if commit:
        user.save()
        business.save()
        return user
```

- I'm not using `cleaned_data`, is that okay?
- What is the purpose of the `if not commit` block in the original code?
- Most importantly, is this a "legitimate way" to handle user registration that requires an automatic object-relation on creation?

Answer (score 1):

- `cleaned_data` is the dictionary of data after all validation in every field in that form. Now you can decide whether to rely on it or not(preferably you should).So as a pseudocode we could say `cleaned_data + errors` will be all fields.
- `commit` is used to decide whether it should commit to db(write). From the above code, to add a related model object like `profile`, the original object(`User`) has to be created first.Thats why it make force commit.
- To add a related object on object creation, there are multiple ways like `post_save` signals, override model `save`, override form `save` etc.So you are using one of good approach, I would say.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to re-assure me. A little follow-up on `commit` if I may: It still isn't really clear to me why if I precede my two `save`s with `if commit:`, then it doesn't work. Isn't commit auto-set to be `True` in the definition? See this [this link](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2011/12/19/quick-example-of-extending-usercreationform-in-django) where the user creation `commit` is first set to False, and then there's an `if commit` block before `save()`

Comment: Also if I can squeeze one more question: The original code returns a tuple of `user, userprofile`, if I try to return `user, business` then I get an error. Where is this return used? and why does it throw me an error?

Comment: These answers you need to check.But check with `super`. You are calling `super(UserCreationForm)` . is it `super(GeneralUserForm)` ? in you first form